# How to use ref in a functional component (expo camera)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm reacting my camera as a functional component but the documentation says

> To use methods that Camera exposes one has to create a component `ref`
> and invoke them using it.

but in react documentation it says that I can not use `ref` in a functional component.

if this the same thing as `useRef`? I'm trying to get the camera to take a picture and save it to my phones memory.

```
    <Camera
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    type={type}
    useCamera2Api={true}
    ratio={"16:9"}

//to take a picture
    ref={ref => {
    this.camera = ref;
  }}
  >
```

...

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          alignSelf: 'flex-end',
          alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}
            onPress={() => async () => {
  if (this.camera) {
    let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
  }}
      >
        <FontAwesome
          name="camera"
          style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: That's right. `useRef` is analogous to what ref does. In fact, any tag with ref={useRefObj} will automatically bind the element to the reference, as far as React is concerned, i hope its same for RN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create one variable to assign with `useRef`

```
const cameraRef = useRef(null)
```

And then use `cameraRef` in ref field like this:

```
<Camera 
   ref = {cameraRef} 
/>
```

And then in your TouchableOpacity you will do it like this:

```
if (cameraRef) {
   const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
```

Comment: Oh this makes sense. So what does the .current for the cameraRef do? I see that come up and i'm confused on what it does.

Comment: .current came from useRef hook. When you use useRef it returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component. You can check it in the Hooks API Reference page https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html .  So all props that you made reference will be inside .current

Comment: @JancerLima your answer works for me but can you explain  why you write `ref = {cameraRef}`, it is really confusing as ref is method of camera component and it is assigned to `{cameraRef}` state and we are using `cameraRef` properties to take the picture

Comment: @mirsahib When you use useRef hook it returns a mutable ref object (check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref ) and you can call this object whatever you want. When we tell the Camera component that cameraRef is the ref object related to that component (ref = {cameraRef}), the cameraRef mutable object will inherit Camera props (we finally make a reference to the Camera component) which allow us to use our mutable object (cameraRef) to make changes to the Camera component. Let me know if I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [cameraRef, setCameraRef] = useState(null)

<Camera
  ref={(ref) => {
     setCameraRef(ref)
   }}
 />
```